# How can I bind xdotool commands in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, xdotools

So I'm trying to use xdotool to rebind some keys in Ubuntu. I've installed xdotools and added the shortcut `xdotool key A` to `alt+k`. However, upon pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> nothing happens.

I'm struggling to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I can bind `nautilus` to <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and launch nautilus without issues. And I can type `xdotool key A` into a shell and see an `A` appearing. So it would seem like all the pieces are in place.

Answer (score 0):

**Option #1 - inline command**

`bash -c "xdotool key A"`

You have to run xdotool from bash. This is a way to do it. `-c` option reads the content of `""` and runs it.

**Option #2 - run a script**

It's quite handy to even simpler things like this put into a bash script file you can easily edit and play with later on.

1. Create script `script.sh`
2. Set executable permissions `sudo chmod a+x script.sh`
3. Assign `bash "/absolute/path/to/script.sh"` to a hotkey.

Comment: This still isn't working for me. Just to be clear, I'm setting the command like so: https://i.imgur.com/b0YeRAz.png

Comment: That's weird, that should work. Have you tried the script option?